# How To Parse Delimiter Comma Separated String For First 4 Values in Java

Tags: java, string, parsing, delimiter

I'm currently trying to parse through a string with the output of `1_3_5_1,1_3_7_1,1_4_9_1`

I have run a for loop:

```
String[] row;
for(String value : selValues.split("\\,")){
            System.err.println("value to be deleted :: "+value);
            for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
                row = value.split("\\_");
                System.out.println("print row :: " + row[0]);
                System.out.println("print row :: " + row[1]);
                System.out.println("print row :: " + row[2]);

            }
```

I'm trying to capture the first 4 separated by "_". What I'm looking for is the row[] to be:
    `row[1,3,5,1]
row[1,3,7,1]
row[1,4,9,1]`

Since these are values I'll be sending to the database in a query.

Right now, my ouptut is just repeating 1,3,5,1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. There may be a better way of doing this. Thanks!

**SOLUTION**

Thanks for everyone's input. I've cleaned it up using them and have this:

```
if(selValues != null && !selValues.trim().equals("")){
        for(String value : selValues.split(",")){
                row = value.split("_");
                try{
                //database call here
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use String.split(","), without the two backslashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to remove the `\\` from the regex.

this will do what you need:

```
@Test
public void split2() {
    String input = "1_3_5_1,1_3_7_1,1_4_9_1";
    String[] csv = input.split(",");
    for(String v : csv) {
        String[] usv = v.split("_");
        System.out.print("[");
        for(int i = 0; i < usv.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(usv[i]);
            if(i < usv.length-1) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}
```

output is

```
[1, 3, 5, 1]
[1, 3, 7, 1]
[1, 4, 9, 1]
```

Comment: @Cthulhu, well yes but it has no use for his input and he didn't mention it in the question. i should not have said `you have to remove` but `you may remove` as it has no use in the posted code

Answer (score 2):

Your inner **for-loop** is unnecessary. Its control variable `i` is unused.
Otherwise, your code gives out the right output.

For larger comma-separated lists, you'd be better off using a csv-reader, instead of working with strings.

**Output:** http://ideone.com/dzaIsh